How to properly subdivide the grid?
How to properly subdivide the grid?
When I use bevel it forms a face with n-gon, how can I on a flat surface get rid of n-gon so that it fits subdivision surface?
modifier used: mirror


You must create enough loopcuts to connect your topology and make "all" faces have 4 vertices (not more, nor less)

@DanielMöller That's a common misconception. It's possible to use triangles and n-gons in subdivision modelling successfully. There is no absolute requirement for all quads. Sometimes deliberate use of triangles or n-gons may even be the best option. It's about how you use them and knowing what to expect. Subdivision result is always quads. It's a valid option here to use all quads like you advice, but certainly not a requirement or a must.

@MartynasŽiemys Yes exactly, that's what I always say. I'm always trying to explain that this "doctrine" of all quad topology is not a must, in some cases it does not matter and is probably less efficient if you're having a hard time figuring out how to get all quads and make a mesh more complex even though not necessary for that specific case and there are even a few times when tris or n-gons might even be the better solution.
